# MVC Requires Rebuild After Modifying View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012

I created a new MVC 4 project with a blank internet application template in VS2012 Ultimate.

For some reason this project requires me to stop and recompile when modifying even just a view or CSS file.  Is there a VS setting or project setting I'm missing here?  I understand that I should have to stop for modifying class files, but why am I having issues with the view?

-Ninja

Comment: Are you sure you're not just getting cached copies of the files?  Have you used Ctrl-F5? or Ctrl-R?

Comment: I'm positive about it not caching.  Using Google Chrome, I've cleared it via ctrl+f5 as well as manually.  This was the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the hosted code is at a different location from where it should be for a default VS solution.

The solution building is copying the code from you solution\project folder into the different location.

Try to check the location of the actual deployment. Depending upon whether you are using IIS, IIS Express there are different ways to know that.